# How to perform function before submitting a Django form

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

There are many SO questions about async functions and how to perform something before sending a POST request. My problem is specific to Django because my CSRF token is lost if I wrap the function in a $.when or do any other solutions.

I want to call a function that in itself sends a GET request to and API and fills certain form fields AND THEN afterward, sends a POST request to Dajngo (because the data isn't populated until the first function completes). I want to perform these functions only after the data is validated with Jquery's ".valid". Any IE compatible methods of doing this?

Heres my JS:

```
  $('#long_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        if ($("#long_form").valid()) {
          $.when(
            finished()).done(function(){
        $('#long_form').unbind('submit').submit();
            $.ajax({
              url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
              type: "POST",
              data: $(this).serialize(),
              success: function (data) {
                console.log("Done")},
              error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert(errorThrown);}})
          })}})
```

Finished() is a function that calls the other functions, including one that sends an GET request to an API. I am also validating the data with jquery before sending to Django which is why I'm using AJAX.

I'm quite new to Django and Ajax so this may be a dumb question, but I can't figure this out on my own. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you sure if all the form data populated from your GET request is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by correct, but I will be validating it with Django ModelForms if you're asking about malicious input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your form data is correct and matching to the Django fields, try adding the CSRF in your ajax call manually. In POST requests, Django normally checks for valid CSRF Token unless you specifically mention in your View code to not check for these tokens. But adding a layer of CSRF validation is preferred.

You can get the CSRF token from cookie using the code below according to the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/).

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

After getting this value, try setting your ajax headers like this

```
type: "POST",
beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);},
```

Try this out. There can be many other reasons, but this also may be the issue. And closely check your Django Terminal for any warnings, errors or status codes. That will help.

Comment: exactly what I needed. Does this create any security problems?

Comment: Did it work? There are no security concerns in this. It is the recommended way of passing CSRF Tokens. Another method is also there, but this one is easier and straightforward and also recommended by Django Docs.

Comment: It worked. However I now send two POST requests. Could be due to this or some other changes I made. Unsure so far. Thank you!